# Using XSL to merge mutliple xml files

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I am trying to merge 2-3 xml files into one file for my system to process. I have reviewed several other posts and arrived at a code that I thought would work using document, but it does not seem to be doing the desired effect.  I am a real novice at this, so the help in really appreciated.  My scheme code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/OrderRequest">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="OrderRequest"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('2.xml')/*/OrderRequest"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('3.xml')/*/OrderRequest"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a sample of the structure of my xml file. Lots of data but all the data I need under OrderRequest

```
<cXML xml:lang="en-US" payloadID="2015-11-06Orders" timestamp="2015-11-06T13:30:11-05:00">
<Header>
 <From>
   <Credential domain="NetworkId">
    <Identity>Order Admin</Identity>
   </Credential>
 </From>
 <To>
   <Credential domain="NetworkId">
    <Identity>fulfillment</Identity>
   </Credential>
 </To>
<Sender><Credential domain="NetworkId"><Identity>admin group</Identity><SharedSecret>hidden</SharedSecret>
</Credential>
<UserAgent>Procurement Sys</UserAgent>
</Sender>
</Header>
<Request>
<OrderRequest>
<OrderRequestHeader orderID="PO12345" orderDate="2015-11-05T13:30:44-05:00" requisitionID="">
<Total><Money currency="USD">34.00</Money>
</Total>
<Shipping>
<Money currency="USD">0.00</Money>
<Description xml:lang="en-US">Next day</Description>
</Shipping>
<Contact>
<Name xml:lang="en">Smith, Bob A.</Name>
<Phone name="default">
<TelephoneNumber>
<CountryCode isoCountryCode="US">1</CountryCode>
<AreaOrCityCode>413</AreaOrCityCode>
<Number>5551234</Number>
<Extension></Extension>
</TelephoneNumber>
</Phone>
</Contact>
</OrderRequestHeader>
<ItemOut quantity="2" lineNumber="1">
<ItemID>
<SupplierPartID>TEX TI30XIIS</SupplierPartID>
</ItemID>
<ItemDetail>
<UnitPrice>
<Money currency="USD">17.00</Money></UnitPrice>
<Description xml:lang="en">Scientific Calculator, Dual Power,2Line, 3-1/5"x6-1/10"x3/4"</Description>
<UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
<Classification domain="UNSPSC">44120000</Classification>
</ItemDetail>
<ShipTo>
<Address isoCountryCode="US" addressID="0001">
<Name xml:lang="en">Sample Location</Name>
<PostalAddress name="default">
<DeliverTo>Smith, Bob</DeliverTo>
<DeliverTo>AR Dept.</DeliverTo>
<Street>Sample Business</Street>
<Street>101 Main St.</Street>
<City>Great Barrington</City>
<State>MA</State>
<PostalCode>01230</PostalCode>
<Country isoCountryCode="US">United States</Country>
</PostalAddress>
<Email name="default"></Email>
<Phone name="default">
<TelephoneNumber>
<CountryCode isoCountryCode="US">1</CountryCode>
<AreaOrCityCode></AreaOrCityCode>
<Number></Number>
<Extension></Extension>
</TelephoneNumber>
</Phone>
</Address>
</ShipTo>
<Distribution>
<Accounting name="General"></Accounting>
<Charge>
<Money currency="USD">34.00</Money>
</Charge>
</Distribution>
</ItemOut>
</OrderRequest>
</Request>
</cXML>
```

Thanks

Comment: @DanielHaley First change removed all nested info below under the <OrderRequest>  and the second suggestion wiped everything but the end cxml tag.

Comment: Sorry the formatting of the input sample threw me off. Please see my answer. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: @DanielHaley The changes did help, and data is coming in now. But if I only use 2 files and there is no "3.xml" it errors and data isn't formatted correctly. Is there a way to account for this or will I need to have a separate XSL for 2 vs 3 files? Thanks –

Comment: It doesn't make sense for it to only work with 2 files and not 3. Can you please update your answer with the edited XSLT and the exact error message?

Comment: @DanielHaley When I need to run this half of the time I have 2 files and the other half the time I have 3 files.  I think you misunderstood it will work with 3 files but the code refers to 3 files. So when I only have two I get an error for msxsl: `code Code:   0x800c0006 
The system cannot locate the object specified.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML sample is correct, the first template (`match="/OrderRequest"`) will never match because `OrderRequest` is not the root element.

I think you should match `Request` and update your `xsl:apply-templates`...

```
  <xsl:template match="Request">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|OrderRequest"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('2.xml')/*/*/OrderRequest"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('3.xml')/*/*/OrderRequest"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Everything else seems ok.